# How to remove /cache dir for Symfony Kernel after running tests?

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit

When running test with Symfony `Kernel`, it creates `/cache` and `/logs` directory.

At the moment I load own [`bootstrap.php`](https://github.com/Symplify/DefaultAutowire/blob/41bf858ca7175a9346b3e3c029e2aad6a3071020/tests/bootstrap.php#L5-L9) file with `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// clear cache
register_shutdown_function(function () {
    Nette\Utils\FileSystem::delete(__DIR__.'/cache');
    Nette\Utils\FileSystem::delete(__DIR__.'/logs');
});
```

1. **I wonder, is there better way to do that?**
2. The best without this extra `bootstrap.php` file?

Note: I don't want to keep `/cache` and `/logs` directory there by adding them to `.gitignore`.

---

Used resources with no help:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement [a test listener](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.examples.SimpleTestListener.php).

<kbd>tests/ClearLogAndCacheTestListener.php</kbd>

```
namespace Symplify\DefaultAutowire\Tests;



class ClearLogAndCacheTestListener extends \PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener
{
    public function endTestSuite(\PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
    {
        \Nette\Utils\FileSystem::delete(__DIR__.'/cache');
        \Nette\Utils\FileSystem::delete(__DIR__.'/logs');
    }

}
```

Then enable  [enable the test listener](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.test-listeners) in your `phpunit.xml` config and remove the custom `autoload.php` from test folder:

<kbd>phpunit.xml</kbd>

```
<phpunit
    bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
    colors="true"
    syntaxCheck="true"
    verbose="true"
>
    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symplify\DefaultAutowire\Tests\ClearLogAndCacheTestListener">
        </listener>
    </listeners>
[...]
</phpunit>
```

Hope this help

Comment: hi @tomáš-votruba check my update if is complaint with your requirement

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It's the best so far so I will try it in practice how it suits.
I was looking for something like "disable Symfony Kernel cache", or "Symfony Kernel shutdown cleanup". Trying to avoid another layer to solve the problem. I'm waiting for other response.

Comment: Btw, it can be shortened to: `<listener class="Symplify\Tests\ClearLogAndCacheTestListener" />`

Also, this listener is run on every test. `$testSuite->getName()` is required, like this: https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/blob/4f1809bbed34a1119ef1f48b8a91a80476e046fd/tests/ClearLogAndCacheTestListener.php#L16-L18